# Проблема при открытии копии потока MemoryStream

Tags: c#, openxml

Есть код который создает из файла поток. Файл содержит шаблонный вариант отчета в формате Open Xml. Затем код делает из этого потока копию, что бы потом можно было эту копию повторно использовать. Это сделано для того что бы не обращаться повторно к диску. Но при обращении к копии stream происходит ошибка при создании объекта **SpreadsheetDocument**.

Вот сама ошибка: 
**DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackageException: The specified package is invalid. The main part is missing.**

```
if (copyStreamIsExist == false)
{
    Log.SetDetal("Первичное открытие файла шаблона");
    var originalStream = File.Open(path + templateName, FileMode.Open);

    originalStream.CopyTo(workMemoryStream);

    copyStream = new MemoryStream();
    workMemoryStream.CopyTo(copyStream);

    copyStreamIsExist = true;

    var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(workMemoryStream, true);
} else {
    Log.SetDetal("Файл шаблона существует в памяти. Делаем копию памяти");
    workMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    copyStream.CopyTo(workMemoryStream);
    workMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(workMemoryStream, true);
}
```

Comment: А вы не забыли перемотать `copyStream` к началу? А то вы небось начинаете копировать не с начала, а с конца.

Comment: Очень верно подмечено! Спасибо! Сделал как вы сказали и все ок стало!

Comment: Тогда оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не перемотали `copyStream` в начало. После копирования в него текущее его положение — в конце, так что когда вы копируете *из* него, начальное положение для копирования совпадает с концом потока.

Добавьте `copyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` перед каждым копированием из него. (Если добавить только после копирования в `copyStream`, то первое копирование из `copyStream` сработает, а второе — нет.)